# Check Laravel 5.7 login from external script

Tags: laravel, encryption, cookies, authentication, external

I have a Laravel app and I need to check if a user is logged and who from a external script. I'm using the following lines to load Laravel and try to check it.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

/*if (Cookie::get(config('session.cookie')) != "") {
    $id = Cookie::get(config('session.cookie'));
    Session::driver()->setId($pericod);
    Session::driver()->start();
}*/

$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
if(!$isAuthorized){
    echo "NO AUTORIZADO";
    exit();
}
```

With this lines I can access any Laravel function and I can check the login if I made `GET` request to the external scripts, but when the request is `POST` it always fails. I'm unable to check the login and I see that the session changes because can't get the existing session.

I have made many tests and I think that somethings of Laravel are not working fine, like routes or middlewares. I can made it work if I disable all encryption of the cookies and the session, but I want to use this security functions.

I'm using updated Laravel 5.7 and I had this code working in Laravel 5.4

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem,

The trick is that the route is external to laravel so laravel's route resolver identifies the current route as /. 
It was working on `GET` requests because in my routes file I have the / route only as get. If I set the / route as any, everything works.

I wasn't seeing the problem because I was not terminating Laravel's execution. If I change the logged user verification to this, it shows the error:

```
$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
if(!$isAuthorized){
    echo "NO AUTORIZADO";

    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

    exit();
}
```

This two lines ends laravel execution and returns the error "405 Method Not Allowed".

```
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Thank you for your help.